# Can't delete registry key though I changed ownership to myself

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I want to completely remove office from registry (under windows 8 32 bits).

But I can't remove a key under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...\OFFICE\Common\Smart Tag\Actions\{...}
```

Though I changed ownership to myself with full control (I use regedit with admin rights of course).

Why ? How to delete this key ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [RegOwnershipEx](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.210) to take ownership of registry keys:

> RegOwnershipEx is an application which allows you to do the following
>   tasks:
>
> - you will be able to take ownership of a registry key with one click (useful to get the full access to the key).
> - you will be able to jump directly to desired registry also with one click.

[image: RegOwnershipEx]

Now try again to delete the keys.

Answer (score 0):

A process may have the key open.

Sysinternal's Process Explorer may be able to help you find and kill the process.  Try killing all `explorer.exe`'s and `iexplore.exe`'s (while `regedit` is open) and then see if the key can be deleted.

You may need to load the key offline from a Windows PE boot disk if nothing else works.  Load the SOFTWARE hive from c:\windows\system32\config.